# Why doesn't deferred function execute?

Tags: for-loop, go, concurrency, channel, defer-keyword

I am trying hard to understand concurrency in Go.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sendValues(myIntChannel chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        myIntChannel <- i //sending value
    }
}

func main() {
    myIntChannel := make(chan int)
    defer close(myIntChannel)
    go sendValues(myIntChannel)

    for value := range myIntChannel {
        fmt.Println(value) //receiving value
    }
}
```

Above code is giving below output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /Users/spikki/Desktop/GoLearning/go_channel.go:51 +0x10b
```

As per my understanding, defer function will execute after completion of its surrounding functions. I am not able to interpret it.

If I use for loop to receive the values from the channel its working as below.

```
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    fmt.Println(<-myIntChannel) //receiving value
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand this concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for ... range` over a channel terminates only once all values have been received from the channel and the channel has been closed.

In your example you wish to close the channel in a deferred function, but that would only run when `main()` returns. But `main()` would only return if the loop would end. This is the cause of deadlock. The `for` loop waits for the channel to be closed, and closing the channel waits for the for loop to end.

When you use a loop to receive exactly 5 values form the channel, it works because the launched goroutines sends 5 values on it. This loop doesn't wait for the channel to be closed, so the loop can end, and so can the `main()` function.

That's why the *sender* should close the channel (not the receiver), and problem is solved immediately:

```
func sendValues(myIntChannel chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        myIntChannel <- i //sending value
    }
    close(myIntChannel)
}

func main() {
    myIntChannel := make(chan int)
    go sendValues(myIntChannel)

    for value := range myIntChannel {
        fmt.Println(value) //receiving value
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SMCh8doGiQr)):

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain it in a bit different terms, what your code does is:

```
func main() {
    ...
    while myIntChannel is not closed {
        ...
    }
    close myIntChannel 
}
```

Now you can see where the deadlock comes from.

While the above answer is valid, you could also try this, if you prefer using `defer`:

```
func sendValues(myIntChannel chan int) {
    defer close(myIntChannel)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        myIntChannel <- i //sending value
    }
}

func main() {
    myIntChannel := make(chan int)

    go sendValues(myIntChannel)

    for value := range myIntChannel {
        fmt.Println(value) //receiving value
    }
}
```